# Как ограничить кол-во символов в EditText?

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы можно было ввести только 4 цифры, с запятой между ними.
Делаю так:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal">
    </EditText>
```

почему ограничение ems не работает?

Comment: Может maxLenght попробовать?

Comment: Да! Все Ок! Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В вашем случае разумно использовать атрибут

> android:maxLength="5"